# How to generate a sequence of numbers while respecting some constraints?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, combinatorics

I need to generate all possible numbers (integers) from 0 to 999999 (without repetition) while respecting a series of constraints.

To better understand the requirements, imagine each number being formed by a 2 digit prefix and a suffix of 4 digits. Like 000000 being read as 00-0000 and 999999 as 99-9999. Now to the rules:

- prefixes must be in random order
- suffixes must be in random order while making sure that each 10k numbers in the sequence have all numbers from 0000 to 9999.
- must be able to generate the numbers again in the same order, given a seed.
- Not really a requirement but it would be great if it was done using Linq.

Thus far, I have written some code that meets all requirements but the first one:

```
var seed = 102111;
var rnd = new Random(seed);
var prefix = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).OrderBy(p => rnd.Next());
var suffix = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).OrderBy(s => rnd.Next());
var result = from p in prefix
                from s in suffix
                select p.ToString("d2") + s.ToString("d4");

foreach(var entry in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(entry);
}
```

Using this I am able to reproduce the sequence by using the same seed, the first 10000 numbers have all numbers from 0000 to 9999, as does the second 10k and so on, but the prefixes are not really random since each 10k group will have the same prefix.

I also thought of creating a class with the number and it's group (100 groups, each group having 10k numbers) to make it easier to shuffle but I believe that are better, simpler ways to do it.

Comment: Just do `var result = Enumerable.Range(0, 100_0000).OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).Select(x => $"{x / 10000:d2}{x % 10000:d4}");`.

Comment: @ckuri thanks but this does not respects the 2nd constraint.

Comment: Your constraints are not really clear. Are you saying that you want the prefixes randomized, and then all the 10000 randomized elements after them? So, say `10-6234, 10-1335, 10-0314, ... 45-0143, 45-9332, ... ` and so on?

Comment: @EricLippert Language barrier for me. I will try to explain differently: both the prefixes and suffixes must be randomized, but I must garantee that if I split the result sequence in groups of 10000 numbers, each group will have all possible suffixes (from 0000 to 9999).

Comment: Let's try to understand the problem by making the numbers smaller. Suppose the prefix and suffix are each one digit, and the prefix is 1, 2 or 3, and the suffix is 4, 5, or 6.  In your scheme, `15, 24, 16, 25, 14, 36, 35, 34, 26` is a valid ordering because (1) this is a permutation of the nine possible numbers, and (2) any substring of length 3 has all of suffixes 4, 5 and 6.  Yes?

Comment: But the permutation `14, 35, 16, 26, 25, 34, 24, 15, 36` is **not** a valid permutation, because there is a substring `16, 26, 25` where there is no `4`. Is that correct? Or, is this a valid permutation because each group of three *starting from the beginning* has 4, 5, 6?

Comment: It would be a valid permutation because each of three starting from the beginning has 4,5,6. :)

Comment: OK, I think I understand the problem and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the idea posted by [ckuri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55227755/how-to-generate-a-sequence-of-numbers-while-respecting-some-constraints/55230415?noredirect=1#comment97190200_55227755) and including the imporvements suggested by [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55227755/how-to-generate-a-sequence-of-numbers-while-respecting-some-constraints/55230415#comment97196247_55230415), you can group the list of numbers by suffix:

```
var prefixLength = 100;
var suffixLength = 10000;

 Enumerable
  .Range(0, prefixLength * suffixLength)
  .OrderBy(number => rnd.Next())
  .GroupBy(number => number % suffixLength)
```

Then, you can flatten the list:

```
Enumerable
 .Range(0, prefixLength * suffixLength)
 .OrderBy(number => rnd.Next())
 .GroupBy(number => number % suffixLength)
 .SelectMany(g => g)
```

Until here, you will have a list of numbers, where, in each 100 lines (prefixLength), the prefixes will be the same. So, you can select them, getting the index of each line:

```
Enumerable
 .Range(0, prefixLength * suffixLength)
 .OrderBy(number => rnd.Next())
 .GroupBy(number => number % suffixLength)
 .SelectMany(g => g)
 .Select((g, index) => new { Index = index, Number = g })
```

Using the index information, you can group the lines applying the mod function, using the prefixLength as a factor:

```
Enumerable
 .Range(0, prefixLength * suffixLength)
 .OrderBy(number => rnd.Next())
 .GroupBy(number => number % suffixLength)
 .SelectMany(g => g)
 .Select((g, index) => new { Index = index, Number = g })
 .GroupBy(g => g.Index % prefixLength, g => g.Number)
```

Finally, you can flatten the list again, and convert the values to string, in order to get the final result:

```
Enumerable
 .Range(0, prefixLength * suffixLength)
 .OrderBy(number => rnd.Next())
 .GroupBy(number => number % suffixLength)
 .SelectMany(g => g)
 .Select((g, index) => new { Index = index, Number = g })
 .GroupBy(g => g.Index % prefixLength, g => g.Number)
 .SelectMany(g => g)
 .Select(number => $"{number/suffixLength:d2}{number%suffixLength:d4}")
```

Comment: Interesting solution. I note that `$"{x / 10000:d2}{x % 10000:d4}"` is an awkward way to write `x.ToString("d6")`.

Comment: Also, if this is the solution you're going with, I'd encourage you to keep it in integers, and then turn it into a sequence of strings at the last moment. This seems to make the translation to strings very early in the pipeline, which will allocate a lot of memory. Notice how my solution keeps the integers as integers until each element is yielded.

Comment: What is the function of the two calls to `ToList`? Why not `SelectMany(g=>g)` ?

Comment: I used the string to group by the elements based on the suffixes, I do not know how to group them using only integers. I agree with you, there is no need for the 'ToList', I just edited the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately there is a problem with your solution. The "suffixes" are always in the same order in every group in your solution.

Comment: Here, I'll show you how to do your solution and keep it in integers, and also we can make the prefixes and suffixes any size we want.

Comment: `var t = new Random();
var p = 3;
var s = 3;
var results = Enumerable.Range(0, p*s).OrderBy(x => t.Next()).GroupBy(x => x % s).SelectMany(g => g).Select((g, i) => new { i, g }).GroupBy(g => g.i % p, g => g.g).SelectMany(g => g).Select(i => (i/p).ToString() + (i%p).ToString()); 
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", results.Take(100)));`

Comment: If we run that code we get, say `12,01,20,22,11,10,02,21,00`. Look at the suffixes: `210, 210, 210`.  The suffixes are no longer randomized when you do the grouping like this.

Comment: Compare that with my solution, that produces outputs such as `00,22,21,01,10,12,02,11,20`.  The suffixes are `021, 102, 210` -- they are *randomized in each group*. And similarly the prefixes are `022011012` -- three of each, but in a random order. I think you have not actually produces a random enough permutation.

Comment: Whoops, small mistake in my comment, that should be `(i/s).ToString() + (i%s).ToString()`.

Comment: @EricLippert Thank you very much for your improvements. I was not concerned about the order between groups, my fault. Totally agree with you. Just edited my answer to include your suggestions.

Comment: This is a great solution. Glad to see Eric contributing for it to become ever better. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 10):

[I've overwritten an earlier, wrong solution based on a misunderstanding of the problem].

---

We start by making a helper method that produces a shuffled range based on a given seed:

```
static IEnumerable<int> ShuffledRange(int size, int seed)
{
  var rnd = new Random(seed);
  return Enumerable.Range(0, size).OrderBy(p => rnd.Next());
}
```

The next thing we're going to do is to randomize all the suffixes and get all of them into a sequence. Note that we use a different seed for each shuffle, but the value of the seed is predictable.

```
static IEnumerable<string> ShuffledIds(int seed)
{
  const int s = 10000;
  const int p = 100;
  var suffixes = Enumerable.Range(0, p)
    .Select(seedOffset => ShuffledRange(s, seed + seedOffset)
    .SelectMany(x => x);
```

We've met the constraint that each chunk of 10000 has all 10000 suffixes, in random order. Now we have to distribute 10000 of each prefix. Let's make a sequence of prefixes for each possible suffix. (Again, we use a not-yet-used seed for each shuffle.)

```
  var dict = new Dictionary<int, IEnumerator<int>>();
  for (int suffix = 0; suffix < s; suffix += 1)
    dict[suffix] = ShuffledRange(p, seed + p + suffix).GetEnumerator();
```

And now we can distribute them

```
  foreach(int suffix in suffixes)
  {
    dict[suffix].MoveNext();
    yield return dict[suffix].Current.ToString("d2") +
     suffix.ToString("d4");
  }
}
```

And that should do it.

Notice that this also has the nice property that the shuffling algorithm is no longer the concern of the code which needs shuffles.  Try to encapsulate details like that in helper functions.

Comment: Your code improves mine because each following group of 10k suffixes will be in a different order, but the problem with the prefixes remain. I need that the preffix change at each number, not at every 10k numbers.

Comment: The edited answer is great and does actually fulfills all requirements, thanks for this!

Answer (score 2):

This solution is inspired by Rodolfo Santos's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55230415/11178549). It improves over his solution by shuffling the numbers inside each group that share the same suffix, completing the randomness of the resulting sequence. The algorithm takes advantage of the fact that LINQ's [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) sorting is stable, so ordering the numbers by prefix does not destroy the previous order by random. If this was not the case, an extra grouping and flattening would be required.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> RandomConstrainedSequence(
    int prefixLength, int suffixLength, int seed)
{
    var random = new Random(seed);
    return Enumerable
    .Range(0, prefixLength * suffixLength)
    .OrderBy(_ => random.Next()) // Order by random
    .OrderBy(n => n / suffixLength) // Order by prefix (randomness is preserved)
    .Select((n, i) => (n, i)) // Store the index
    .GroupBy(p => p.n % suffixLength) // Group by suffix
    // Suffle the numbers inside each group, and zip with the unsuffled stored indexes
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(_ => random.Next()).Zip(g, (x, y) => (x.n, y.i)))
    .SelectMany(g => g) // Flatten the sequence
    .OrderBy(p => p.i) // Order by the stored index
    .Select(p => p.n); // Discard the index and return the number
}
```

Usage example:

```
int index = 0;
foreach (var number in RandomConstrainedSequence(5, 10, 0))
{
    Console.Write($"{number:00}, ");
    if (++index % 10 == 0) Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Output:

> 44, 49, 47, 13, 15, 00, 02, 01, 16, 48,
>   25, 30, 29, 41, 43, 32, 38, 46, 04, 17,
>   23, 19, 35, 28, 07, 34, 20, 31, 26, 12,
>   36, 10, 22, 08, 27, 21, 24, 45, 39, 33,
>   42, 18, 09, 03, 06, 37, 40, 11, 05, 14,

---

**Update:** This solution can be generalized to solve a larger spectrum of problems, where the sorting is constrained into each subgroup of a sequence. Here is an extension method that does exactly that:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> OrderGroupsBy<TSource, TGroupKey, TOrderKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TGroupKey> groupByKeySelector,
    Func<TSource, TOrderKey> orderByKeySelector)
{
    return source
        .Select((x, i) => (Item: x, Index: i))
        .GroupBy(e => groupByKeySelector(e.Item))
        .Select(group =>
        {
            var itemsOrdered = group.Select(e => e.Item).OrderBy(orderByKeySelector);
            var indexesUnordered = group.Select(e => e.Index);
            return itemsOrdered.Zip(indexesUnordered, (x, i) => (Item: x, Index: i));
        })
        .SelectMany(group => group)
        .OrderBy(pair => pair.Index)
        .Select(pair => pair.Item);
}
```

The effects of this method can be more clearly seen with a different example. An array of names are ordered, but the ordering is constrained inside each subgroup of names starting with the same letter:

```
var source = new string[] { "Ariel", "Billy", "Bryan", "Anton", "Alexa", "Barby" };
Console.WriteLine($"Source: {String.Join(", ", source)}");
var result = source.OrderGroupsBy(s => s.Substring(0, 1), e => e);
Console.WriteLine($"Result: {String.Join(", ", result)}");
```

```xml
Source: Ariel, Billy, Bryan, Anton, Alexa, Barby
Result: Alexa, Barby, Billy, Anton, Ariel, Bryan
```

Using this extension method, the original problem can be solved like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> RandomConstrainedSequence(
    int prefixLength, int suffixLength, int seed)
{
    var random = new Random(seed);
    return Enumerable
        .Range(0, prefixLength * suffixLength)
        .OrderBy(_ => random.Next()) // Order by random
        .OrderBy(n => n / suffixLength) // Order again by prefix
        // Suffle each subgroup of numbers sharing the same suffix
        .OrderGroupsBy(n => n % suffixLength, _ => random.Next());
}
```